# Random text generator (same order every time)

Tags: text, random, label, ios6, xcode4.5

hi im creating a app that generates random text when i press a button at the moment i have the code and it works fine but there are some things i would like to change when i run the app and i press the button it shows:

"alright, hiya, yoo, yoo, Hello, alright, Hiya, yoo, yoo, hiya, hello, hello, alright"

thats the first 13 clicks and thats the order every time i go on the app. Basically i dont want them to repeat twice in a row and also i want them to start in different orders when i start the app.

1 more thing i would like to be able to write at least 2 lines of text but how do i do that using a Label?

heres the code i have:

.h

```
@interface ViewController1 : UIViewController  {

    IBOutlet UILabel *textview;

}

-(IBAction)random;
```

.m

@interface ViewController1 ()

@end

@implementation ViewController1

-(IBAction)random {

```
int text = rand() % 5;

switch (text) {

    case 0:

        textview.text = @"Hello";

        break;

    case 1:

        textview.text = @"hi";

        break;

    case 2:

        textview.text = @"alright";

        break;

    case 3:

        textview.text = @"yoo";

        break;

    case 4:

        textview.text = @"hiya";

        break;

    default:

        break;

}
```

}

thank you :)

Comment: Call `srand((unsigned)time(0));` once, and once only, before the first call to rand().  That should start rand() at a different place every time you run your program.

Comment: @rossum sorry what do you mean could you show me/tell me please thank you

Comment: Put the call to `srand()` somewhere in your start-up code so it is called once at the start of your program.  Somewhere near the start of `main()` if you can.  The basics are to only ever call it once, and to call it before the first invocation of `rand()`.  The code you have shown us looks like it is called more than once, so `srand()` doesn't fit in there.  Use `main()` or an equivalent startup method.

Comment: sorry bud im confused can you edit my code and show me please ??

Comment: the call needs to go in part of the code you haven't posted.

Comment: -(IBAction)random {
    
    int text = arc4random() % 50;
    
    switch (text) {
            
        case 0:
            
            textview.text = @"my text here.";
            
            break;
                    
        default:
            
            break;
            
    }
    
}

Comment: is that what you needed friend

Comment: @rossum have a look at my answer at the bottom and could you edit the code in there because i don't known what you mean my friend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the function `arc4random()` instead of `random()`. The problem you face is because the function `rand` needs a seed to be set before you call it. This is a starting value for the random number generator used in the background by `rand`. When you don't use a own seed it's always the same default, and you therefore always get the same sequence of random values. When using `arc4random` there is no need for setting a seed. For further information see [this blog post](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.co.at/2008/10/random-thoughts-rand-vs-arc4random.html) and the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/arc4random.3.html).

```
#include <stdlib.h>
...
int text = arc4random() % 5;
```

Comment: Thanks do you known how i can have two lines of text ??

Answer (score 0):

```
@interface ViewController1 ()

@end

@implementation ViewController1



-(IBAction)random {

    // Pseudocode here
    if (srand() not yet called) then
      srand();
    endif
    // end Pseudocode

    // You are better to put the call to srand() somewhere 
    // it will only ever be called once, rather than having
    // to mess around with an if-statement.

    int text = arc4random() % 50;

    switch (text) {

        case 0:

            textview.text = @"My text here";

            break;

   default:

            break;

    }

}
```